# how to suppress a global ajaxStart / ajaxStop for a specific ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use something like the following for handling an ajax loading timer:

```
  $body = $("body");
  $(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function() { $body.addClass("loading");    },
    ajaxStop: function() { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
  });
```

but there are some specific calls where I want this suppressed. How would I do this? I don't want to manually removed the loading class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `global:false` option to specific ajax calls.

`ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` are global handlers. If you don't want some ajax calls to be suppressed, just add `global:false` to your ajax.

### 1

```
$.ajax({
  url:'some url',
  success: function(){
       // this ajax will trigger ajax start and stop
  }
});
```

### 2

```
$.ajax({
   url:'some url',
   success: function(){
       // this ajax will not trigger ajax start and stop as it has global set to false
   },
   global: false
});
```

Comment: @timpone glad to have helped ;)